# Is there an easy way to randomize all the words in a given text? Maybe in BASH?

Tags: python, bash

I want to randomize all the words in a given text, so that I can input a file with English like

```
"The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs."
```

and have it output:

```
"fox jumped lazy brown The over the dogs. quick"
```

The easiest way I can think to do it would be to import the text into python, put it into a dictionary with a seqence of numbers as keys, then randomize those numbers and get the output. Is there an easier way to do this, maybe from the command-line, so that I don't have to do too much programming?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

quick and dirty:

```
echo ".."|xargs -n1 |shuf|paste -d' ' -s
```

your example:

```
kent$  echo "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs."|xargs -n1 |shuf|paste -d' ' -s
the jumped quick dogs. brown over lazy fox The
```

if you don't have `shuf`, `sort -R` would work too. same idea.

Comment: even simpler: `shuf -e The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs. | paste -sd' '`.

Answer (score 4):

**Quick Solution:**

You can randomize lines with **sort -R** in bash. **tr** will do string replacement.

example:

```
echo ".." | tr -s " " "\n" | sort -R | tr "\n" " "; echo
```

will randomize a string separated by spaces.

Another variation would be converterting all non alphanumerical characters to newlines

```
| tr -cs 'a-zA-Z0-9' '\n'
```

explanation:

```
# tr -c       all NOT matching 
# tr -s       remove all dublicates )
```

-> randomimizing the lines

```
| sort -R
```

-> replacing all newlines with spaces

```
| tr "\n" " "
```

-> removing the last space with sed

```
| sed "s/ *$//"
```

> and finally adding a dot ( and a newline )

```
; echo "."
```

**Finally : A function to make a real new sentence from another sentence**

*Features ignoring dublicate space and removing all non-alphanumeric*

*reading the output makes you sound like master yoda ...*

```
sentence="This sentence shall be randomized...really!"

echo $sentence | tr -cs 'a-zA-Z0-9' '\n' | sort -R | tr "\n" " " | sed "s/ *$//"; echo "."
```

Output examples:

```
randomized This shall be sentence really.
really be shall randomized This sentence.

...
```

**Addition: sed explaination** 
*( i know you want it ... )*

```
sed "s/bla/blub/"           # replace bla with blub
sed "s/bla*$/blub/"         # replace the last occurence of bla with blub
sed "s/ *$//"               # -> delete last space aka replace with nothing
```

would only shuffle the words.

Comment: yes should work as expected. updated my answer with full example.

Comment: You might want to add a final newline by adding `; echo` after the pipeline.

Answer (score 4):

In Python:

```
>>> import random
>>> s = "I want to randomize all the words in a given text, so that I can input a file with English like "
>>> words = s.split()
>>> random.shuffle(words)
>>> ' '.join(words) 
'words I so like a can the text, I want a randomize input given with to in all that English file'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Python, from a bash prompt:

```
echo "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs." | \
python -c "import random, sys; x = sys.stdin.read().strip().split(' '); \
random.shuffle(x); sys.stdout.write('\"{}\"\n'.format(' '.join(x)))"
```